# Can I make typescript (or a tool like eslint) error if a library returns any?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm using [knex](http://knexjs.org/) and it occasionally returns `any`, e.g. if I forget to specify the type of the table I'm querying.

Is there any tooling I can use to prevent this from happening, so I'm forced to type all my knex queries?

Answer (score 0):

**You may want to force type declaration to avoid any using this eslint rule:**

[no-explicit-any](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md)

Comment: This rule is already turned on and doesn't catch this case, because the `any` is returned by an external library.